# How to concatenate a regex match and a string variable without spaces or other characters?

Tags: powershell

I want to replace a date with regex in a file in Powershell. All whitespacing needs to be preserved:

```
#define    BUILD_DATE          20181010
```

The current date is a variable:

```
[string]$Today = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d"
```

I learned to use backticks when using a match in replace expression:

```
(Get-Content $ItemFullPath) |
Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "(#define\s+?BUILD_DATE\s+?)\S+", "`$1$Today" } |
Set-Content $ItemFullPath
```

But this leads to:

```
#define    BUILD_DATE          $Today
```

I cannot add another space character here. There are other readers and writers of this file which expect that very same whitespace to be present.

Comment: Try using $($Today), this should evaluate the variable properly. Check here for more details - https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html

Comment: This does not work. Result is: `$120181012`. So the regex match is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use curly brackets so that PowerShell and the regex engine aren't confused about where one variable/backreference ends and the other begins. Also, the `ForEach-Object` isn't needed here, since the `-replace` operator works as an enumerator and can thus be used on arrays directly.

```
(Get-Content $ItemFullPath) -replace "(#define\s+?BUILD_DATE\s+?)\S+", "`${1}$Today" } |
    Set-Content $ItemFullPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a RegEx with a nonconsuming [look behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion,
there is no reason to reference the capture group in the replace.

This script updates the date in it's own source code.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\10\12\SO_52775631.ps1

#define    BUILD_DATE          20181010

$ItemFullPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name

[string]$Today = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d"

(Get-Content $ItemFullPath) -replace "(?<=#define\s+?BUILD_DATE\s+?)\d{8}", $Today |
Set-Content $ItemFullPath
```

Comment: This approach does not change that line. So there is no replace.

Comment: @ChristophThien It does, but as I had posted the already changed date you won't see a difference. The `\d{8}` part is outside the look behind and ***is*** replaced by `$Today`